# Basic example of forwarding tables

Tags: routing, ipv4, ip-forwarding-table

[image: Network]

This is my network. The forwarding tables I provide them bellow. I am able to establish the connection between Office1 and R1 but I am not able to connect with R2, as for a reason I do not know, all the traffic from R1 goes to Office1, ignoring the forwarding table.

**Office 1:**

```
/sbin/ip route add 10.0.6.205/24 via 10.0.6.181
```

**R1:**

```
/sbin/ip route add 10.0.6.1/25 via 10.0.6.177
/sbin/ip route add 10.0.6.185/24 via 10.0.6.181
```

**R2:**

```
/sbin/ip route add 10.0.6.1/30 via 10.0.6.177
```

Does anyone know where am I failing when configuring this basic routing exercise using CORE emulator?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Office1 and R1 aren't on the same network -- even the network mask is different.

R1 and R2 aren't on the same network neither: R1 is on the 10.0.6.180/30 where R2 is on 10.0.6.184/30, so that point-to-point link is never going to work.

Additionally, once you set up correct IP addresses for all interfaces, we'd need to know the routing tables from all devices to be able to troubleshoot the problem.